# Homology of $\Bbb R^3 - (S^1\vee S^1)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $X = \Bbb R^3 - C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary embedding of $S^1\vee S^1$ into $\Bbb R^3$. Compute $H_*(X)$.

I already computed that for arbitrary $S^1$ embedding into $\Bbb R^3$,
$$H_n(\Bbb R^3 - S^1)\simeq\begin{cases}
\Bbb Z & n = 0,1,2\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$
Let $C = A\vee B$ where $A\cong S^1\cong B$. Then $\Bbb R^3-C = (\Bbb R^3-A)\cap (\Bbb R^3-B)$ and $(\Bbb R^3-A)\cup(\Bbb R^3-B) = \Bbb R^3-\{p\}\simeq S^2$. From Mayer-Vietoris sequence
$$\cdots\to\tilde{H}_{n+1}(\Bbb R^3-\{p\})\to\tilde{H}_n(\Bbb R^3-C)\to\tilde{H}_n(\Bbb R^3-A)\oplus\tilde{H}_n(\Bbb R^3-B)\to\cdots$$
I can conclude $H_n(X) = 0$ for $n\geq 3$. For degree $1,2$ I get
$$0\to\tilde{H}_2(\Bbb R^3-C)\to\tilde{H}_2(\Bbb R^3-A)\oplus\tilde{H}_2(\Bbb R^3-B)\xrightarrow{\varphi}\tilde{H}_2(S^2)\to\tilde{H}_1(\Bbb R^3-C)\to\tilde{H}_1(\Bbb R^3-A)\oplus\tilde{H}_1(\Bbb R^3-B)\to 0.$$
I can say $\tilde{H}_2(\Bbb R^3- C)$ is not zero and I want to say it's $\Bbb Z$ since if we consider an obvious embedding of $S^1\vee S^1$ to $\Bbb R^3$, $H_2\simeq \Bbb Z$. I think once I show $\varphi$ is nontrivial then I can conclude $\tilde{H}_2\not\simeq\Bbb Z^2$ so $\simeq\Bbb Z$. But don't know how to. Please help.

Edit: Computing $H_n(\Bbb R^3 - C)$ where $S^1\cong C\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^3$ is an arbitrary embedding:
Choose $p\in\Bbb R^3\setminus C$. Then $H_*(S^3-C,S^3 - C - \{p\})\simeq H_*(S^3-C,\Bbb R^3-C)\simeq H_*(\Bbb R^3,\Bbb R^3 - \{p\})$ by excision. From l.e.s of pair $(\Bbb R^3,\Bbb R^3 - \{p\})$, $\tilde{H}_n(\Bbb R^3,\Bbb R^3-\{p\})\simeq\tilde{H}_{n-1}(S^2)$. Now, from the l.e.s.
$$\cdots\to H_{n+1}(S^3-C,\Bbb R^3-C)\to H_n(\Bbb R^3-C)\to H_n(S^3-C)\to\cdots$$
I conclude
$$H_n(\Bbb R^3-C)\simeq\begin{cases}
\Bbb Z & n = 0,1,2\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Here, I used the fact that $H_*(S^3 - C)\cong H_*(S^1)$.

Comment: Do you know a generator for H2(R3-A)?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I don't know what it should be. The embedding of $S^1$ is arbitrary.

Comment: How did you compute the homology of the complement of a circle? I'd be surprised if that did not give you generators.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I edited the post. I can find the generator algebraically using isomorphisms but can't see what the generator looks like in the actual space.

Comment: Let us put it this way: can you write a sequence of isomorphism from group you know to $H_2(\mathbb RR^3-S^1)$? What you wrote is a lot of information, but what we need is hidden there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$Let $A$ be one of your circes, $x$ the point in which it touches the other circle. We have the following diagram

[image]

The left column is how you computed $H_2(\RR^3-A)$. The arrow $H_3(S^3)\to H_3(S^3,S^3-p)$ is from the l.e.s of th epair $(S^3-p,S^3)$, the map marked
$\mathrm{incl}_*$ is an isomorphism given by excision, the equal sign is just the fact that $\RR^3=S^3-p$, and the last one is the connecting morphism for the pair $(\RR^3-A,S^3-A)$.

The horizontal arrows are all induced by inclusions, and the sqaure commute because of the naturality of l.e.s. The red map ad the bottom is one of the two components of the map $\phi$ you want to compute.

If you do this with $B$ instead of $A$ you get the same thing, of course, and the right column of the diagram is the same, actually, for both circles. and this means that up the map $\phi$ is $(u,v)\in\mathbb Z^2\mapsto u+v\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The fact that the maps oin the first column of the diagram are all isos means that $H_2(\mathbb R^3-A)$ is generated by the homology class of (any triangulation of) a $2$-sphere that contains $A$ in its interior.

Comment: So the inclusion map $H_2(\Bbb R^3 - A)\to H_2(\Bbb R^3 - C)$ induces an isomorphism. Thank you